# angular2 router dose not work when "loadChildren" loading modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a router definition like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    "path": "member",
    "loadChildren": "app/member/member.module#MemberModule"
},
{
    "path": "",
    "loadChildren": "app/video/video.module#VideoModule"
},
{
    "path": "**",
    "redirectTo": ""
}
]
```

MemberRouter definition like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    "path": "order",
    "component": MemberComponent,
    "loadChildren": "app/member/order/order.module#OrderModule"
},
{
    "path": "",
    "component": MemberComponent,
    "loadChildren": "app/member/index/index.module#IndexModule"
}
]
```

OrderRouter definition like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    "path": "list",
    "outlet": "member",
    "component": OrderComponent,
    "loadChildren": "app/member/order/list/list.module#ListModule"
},
{
    "path": "",
    "outlet": "member",
    "component": OrderComponent
}
]
```

ListRouter definition like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    "path": "",
    "outlet": "order",
    "component": ListComponent
}
]
```

It dose not work at "/member/order/list"

It is working at "/member/order"

"OrderRouter" rules can not be matched when "MemberRouter" is lazy loaded

"loadChildren" dose not work when nested

Please help me solve, thank you!

[Plunker Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/r0ofl7keNwlSvcU7sxdF/) Click "product/detail/item" button dose no work.

Comment: Do you have `<router-outlet name="member">` tag in your html?

Comment: @ulubeyn `<router-outlet name="member">` tag in my html. router is match '/member/order' url, but is not match '/member/order/list'.

Comment: Hi @MR.HZ do you find a solution for this? Can you please see my case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553844/angular-2-nested-module-with-own-routes i have the same scenario that you have, except that for mi don't work any children route