# Angular 2 nested module with own routes

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I have a project on Angular 2 that have this structure:

```
++ /
--- app.module.ts
+++ dashboard 
---- dashboard.module.ts
---- dashboard.routes.ts
++++ adminarea
----- adminarea.module.ts
----- adminarea.routes.ts
++++++ user
------- usermanagement.component.html
------- usermanagement.component.ts
++++ home
++++ user
```

So, on my **app.module.ts** i import **dashboard.module.ts**.

On **dashboard.module.ts** i have the main route app. 
On **dashboard.component.html** i have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
On this router-outlet i render my adminarea.component.html

Everything is working good here. If i put on my browser: `http://localhost:3000/adminarea` then is render.

But, i need that into adminarea folder another sub folders with other features (list users, list of options...). So i create **adminarea.module.ts** and **adminarea.routes.ts** for manage the routes of these children components into **adminarea.component.html**. Here i put a new `<router-outlet name="adminarea"><router-outlet>`

If i put here on my browser http://localhost:3000/adminarea/usermanagement trows a many errors.

Here is a screenshot with the error:

[image: Angular error]

Here is my files:

**dashboard.routes.ts**

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
... many imports
import { AdminareaModule } from './adminarea/adminarea.module';

export const MODULE_ROUTES: Route[] =[
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'adminarea', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: () => AdminareaModule },
    { path: '**', component: DashboardComponent }

]

export const MODULE_COMPONENTS = [
    HomeComponent,
    UserComponent,
    ...
]
```

**adminarea.routes.ts**

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

import { UserManagementComponent } from './user-management/user-management.component'
import { AdminareaComponent } from "./adminarea.component";

export const MODULE_ADMINAREA_ROUTES: Route[] =[
    {path: '', component: AdminareaComponent, 
            children:[
                {
                    path: 'usermanagement', component: UserManagementComponent, outlet: 'adminarea'
                }]
    }, 
]
```

**adminarea.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {UserManagementComponent} from './user-management/user-management.component';
import {AdminareaComponent} from './adminarea.component';
import {MODULE_ADMINAREA_ROUTES} from './adminarea-routes';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(MODULE_ADMINAREA_ROUTES)
    ],
    declarations : [
        UserManagementComponent,
        AdminareaComponent
    ],
    providers : [

    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AdminareaModule {}
```

Can you help me please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can decribe your nested module routes like this  `loadChildren: 'app/name/my.module#MyModule`

Comment: Yes @BabarBilal i already just done and the same...

Comment: Error seems fairly specific. Are you using `SystemJS`? If so you need to add a script tag that references it.

Comment: Yes i'm using Systemjs my friend @AluanHaddad... How can do this?

Comment: It looks like browser is trying to reference a top level script from a subdirectory. Make sure you set `<base href="/">`

Comment: I have this on my index.html my friend @AluanHaddad